# How to download FLDAS data from earth data

Tags: atmosphere, weatherdata, nasa

I am trying to download transpiration and snow cover data from earth data but unable to figure out how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the data from earth data, the following needs to be done

1. Go to https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/ and create an account. Note the username and password which will be used to download the data.
2. In your linux root create a file .netrc and enter the following

   ```
   machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login your_login password your_password
   ```
3. Go to https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets and search your dataset of interest and then click it

4.On the right hand side you will see a get data button, click that button.

5.Now a dialog box will open, click get data

6. Now another dialog box will open, click download links list, a list of the files will get downloaded.
7. Now in the terminal fire the following command

   ```
   wget --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --auth-no-challenge=on --keep-session-cookies --content-disposition -i <url.txt>
   ```

Meanwhile before step 7 two things need to be done. One, you need to just create this file ~/.urs_cookies and the second is that you have to authorize the data that you are downloading.